# Установка vue в новом версий laravel7

Tags: laravel, vue.js, npm, laravel7

Все делаю как в показано в документаций, но как то node_modules и vue не совместимо кажется. Когда frontend была на чистом js все отлично работало, но проблема появилась когда подключил vue на проект. Node modules перестал работать. npm run dev выдает следующий ошибку

@ development: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js`

Можете написать все этапы от А до Я как правильно устанавливать vue на laravel7 (новая версия). Все делаю как в документаций, но не получается

```
events.js:174
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:240:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:415:16)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:834:11)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:623:3)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:246:12)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:415:16)
    [... lines matching original stack trace ...]
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:623:3)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ development: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @ development script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/alibek/.npm/_logs/2020-03-16T19_56_59_915Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ dev: `npm run development`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @ dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Answer (score 1):

Установите пакет ui:

```
composer require laravel/ui
```

Из этого пакета ставится Vue командой:

```
php artisan ui vue
```

Дальше для установки всех зависимостей надо из корня проекта прописывать команду

```
npm install
```

Далее настройте файл `webpack.mix.js` в корне проекта для компиляции файлов из папки `resources`.  Подробнее об этом здесь: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/mix#running-mix

Этот способ точно ничего в Laravel сломать не должен.

Comment: уже не стоит, вы устарели.

Comment: @n.osennij Хмм... Быстро они... Обновил.

Answer (score 0):

Запустите:

```
npm install webpack --save
```